# PyQt5 - Updating a QLabel with a QPixmap doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt

this is my `QWidget` class:

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0
        self.move(125,250)
        self.img = None

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
        self.label.setUpdatesEnabled(True)

        self.show()
    def setWidth(self,width):
        self.width = width
        self.resize(self.width,self.height)
        self.img = QImage(self.width,self.height,QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    def setHeight(self,height):
        self.height = height
        self.resize(self.width, self.height)
        self.img = QImage(self.width, self.height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    def setPixel(self,x,y,color):
        self.img.setPixel(x,y,QColor(color.r,color.g,color.b,1).rgb())
    def updateScreen(self,samples):
        painter = QPainter(self.img)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.yellow))
        painter.drawText(10,10,str(samples))
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.img))
        self.label.update()
        self.update()
```

I have a `Window` instance in a second class called `Renderer` which uses the `Window` Object like this:

```
class Renderer:
    def __init__(self,scene,width,height,camera):
        self.buffer = [0] * (self.width * self.height * 3 + 1)

        self.qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = Window()
        self.window.setWidth(self.width)
        self.window.setHeight(self.height)
    def updateScreen(self):
        i = 0
        for w in range(0,self.width):
            for h in range(0,self.height):
                r = self.buffer[i * 3 + 0] / self.samples
                g = self.buffer[i * 3 + 1] / self.samples
                b = self.buffer[i * 3 + 2] / self.samples
                self.window.setPixel(w,h,Color(r,g,b))
                i += 1
        self.window.updateScreen(self.samples)
    def renderOneSample(self):
        self.calculate()
```

I use `Renderer` like this:

```
renderer = Renderer(scene,125,125,Point3D(0.0,0.0,10.0))

for i in range(0,4):
    renderer.calculate()
    renderer.updateScreen()

sys.exit(renderer.qApp.exec_())
```

I would like to see every step in my GUI (1,2,3,4) and not only step 4. I have to update the GUI in another thread, how would i do that?

Comment: I think the problem is that i call `sys.exit(qApp.exec_())` after the first update. Because of that the second `setPixel` doesn't do anything. How can i display my widget without calling `sys.exit(qApp.exec_())`?

Comment: If i do it like this, i get a window for the first `updateScreen` call. If i close this window, the window for the second `updateScreen` call opens...Very strange

Comment: Nope. The `sys.exit(qApp.exec_())` is the same as the equivalent in C++ namely `return app.exec()` that you put inside your `main.cpp`. It enters the main loop where your Qt application lives until `exit()` is triggered from somewhere.Without it you don't start the event loop and you basically don't do anything. :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me, i am sorry. I have to call `sys.exit(qApp.exec_())` otherwise the `QWidget` would close almost instantaneously after i call `show()`. The problem is, that code after `sys.exit...` is not executed until i close the current window. Code after `sys.exit...` is basically my second `updateScreen` call. Why is it so confiusing and how can i fix it?

Comment: `sys.exit(...)` does what the names says - it quites your application. Its argument is an integer, which the `qApp.exec_()` returns whenever an exit event is triggered in your Qt application. That's all. Everything after a call of `sys.exit(...)` will clearly not be executed since the application would have already quit. Also `self.show()` shouldn't be called like that. If I understand correctly `updateScreen(...)` is something that you want to call over and over again. A single `self.show()` at the end of the constructor of your widget would work just fine.

Comment: Please post a working example since you are referring to code that is currently not something that we see.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I updated my code. It is still not updating the second time :(

Comment: What made you want to call `exec()` in a place like this? I think you are missing fundamental knowledge about how Qt works. What is `qApp`? Please don't tell me that this is indeed a `QApplication` instance...

Comment: It is indeed a `QApplication` instance. Could you please explain how it would be done in a correct / good way?

Comment: @binaryBigInt. Please edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I did, i am sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: I always recommend the [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/widgets) tutorials. The provide a lot of the basic stuff and you can also use these as a base to build your own application upon. But since (as I've already mentioned) you lack some basic knowledge in how Qt works, I would suggest also looking at the official C++ documentation and tutorials (there are a lot PyQt equivalents of these tutorials out there, just google, read and learn).

Comment: @binaryBigInt. You didn't. And the inconvenience is only to you, since it is very difficult for anyone to answer your question as it stands. The code you've posted is not in any way complete: what are `scene`, `Point3D`, `Color`, `samples` and `calculate()`? And more to the point, what are you actually trying to achieve with this code?